# How to add a condition to enter a value in free form text field when Other is picked from a drop down

Tags: java, selenium

I used the piece of code blow to pick a value randomly in a drop down, but i forgot that there is a value call Other which require the user to fill in a free form text. Please guide me on how to add this condition. Thank you so much

I tried to add some condition myself but i am a newbie so i didnt get much out of it.

```
WebElement ethnicityDropDownList = 
driver.findElement(By.id("ethnicity"));

//Using Select Class to fetch the count
Select ethnicityObjSel = new Select(ethnicityDropDownList);
List <WebElement> webListEthinicty = ethnicityObjSel.getOptions();

//Taking the count of items
int eCnt = webListEthinicty.size();
```

Random numEthnicity = new Random();
int eSelect = numEthnicity.nextInt(eCnt);

//Selecting value from DropDownList
ethnicityObjSel.selectByIndex(eSelect);

I added a piece of code below and i wonder if it is correct. I tried selectedValue but i got error so i switched it to eSelect == 16 which is Other in the drop down

```
ethnicityObjSel.selectByIndex(eSelect);
   if (eSelect == 16 ) { 
  //if(ethnicityObjSel.selectedValue.equals("Other"){ 

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3] 
   /div/div/form/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/input ")).sendKeys("Slavic"); }
   else{ System.out.println("Other Passed"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

**A test failure should always indicate a bug in the code.** No exceptions.

Your test does not follow the above rule, because the test is flaky. A **flaky test** is a test which could fail or pass given the same configuration. Randomly selecting paths/inputs in a single test is going to create a flaky test.

If you ever have an `if` statement inside of a test, it may be time to split the test out.

You need to think very hard about the single intention of your test.

If your test is actually confirming the functionality of the `ethnicityDropDownList`, then you should be covering each case separately, especially if one of them has significantly different behavior.

Comment: +1. Not the answer the OP was looking for, but this is the answer they need. Choosing a random option is good, *except when "Other" is chosen.* The "Other" test case should be separate. This test case should be "choose a random option, except 'Other'".

Comment: Yeah, I am definitely diving into personal opinion when I say not to choose a random option ever. However I stand by it, since if yet **another**  option is added to the drop-down at a later time that creates yet **another** new path, it could also unexpectedly break the test at a later time.

Comment: thank you for all the inputs, i think these are very good pointers which help me improve my skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if-else` block and check if the selected value is 'Other'

```
ethnicityObjSel.selectByIndex(eSelect);
if(ethnicityObjSel.selectedValue().equals('Other'){
//Process your logic
}
else{
// Process your logic
}
```

Comment: For some reason i get an error for the selectedValue (cannot be resolved or not in a field) . So i came up with this method but not sure if it is going to work. Can some one verify this piece of code for me please?

Comment: if (eSelect == 14 ) {
     //if(ethnicityObjSel.selectedValue.equals("Other"){
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/input ")).sendKeys("Slavic");
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("Other Passed"); 
     }

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you check now. it should be `selectedValue()` as a function.